# Could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.4": No such file or directory

Tags: postgis, extensions

When trying to make the postgis_tiger_geocoder extension and running 'make installcheck' I get the following error:

```
could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.4": No such file or directory
```

Searching for 'postgis-2.4' proves that it does not exist.

I get the same error if I try to install the extensions into a database through the psql interface.

I have seen one ticket with the same problem on this site and the answer was to re-install the software with a different version, but I was hoping there was a more targeted solution. There seem to be so many incompatibilities to overcome that re-installing the software seems likely to solve one problem but then present me with a whole list of other problems.

I have installed postgreSQL 9.6.9 and postGIS 2.4.5.

Comment: what type of machine are you on? how did you install postgis?

Comment: Hi Ian, I am on a Centos 7 machine. Postgis was installed by downloading a tar, unzipping it in situ and using the configuration, make and build instructions.

Comment: did you set the libdir variable to point to where ever you installed the postgis libraries?

Comment: Yes, I tried ./configure --with-pgconfig=/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/pg_config

Comment: And then later added more declared paths but still the problem persisted. ./configure --with-pgconfig=/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/pg_config --with-gdalconfig=/usr/bin/gdal-config --with-geosconfig=/usr/bin/geos-config --with-xml2config=/usr/bin/xml2-config --with-libiconv=/usr/bin --with-gui --with-raster

Answer (score 1):

The solution was a little drastic but it appears to have worked. The available packages and support for Centos appeared limited compared to Ubuntu. I therefore re-purposed the server to run Ubuntu and so far the install appears to have been succesful.